# How can I calculate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2+ix}dx$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, improper-integrals, complex-integration, substitution

We know that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}dx = \sqrt{\pi}$$

How can I use it to find $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2+ix}dx$$

Is it legal in this case to make following variable substitution: $t = x - \frac{i}{2}$? How and why will the integration contour change?

Comment: Complete the square first, and use Cauchy's theorem. See [Calculating integral (actually calculating Fourier transform)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4058114/568204) for part of the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Feynman trick if you want to avoid complex integrals. Define $$f(\alpha)=\int_{\mathbb R} e^{-x^2+\alpha x}dx$$
Then $$\begin{split}
f^\prime (\alpha)&=\int_{\mathbb R} xe^{-x^2+\alpha x} dx \\
&= -\frac 1 2\int_{\mathbb R} \left(-2x +\alpha\right)e^{-x^2+\alpha x} dx+\frac \alpha 2 f(\alpha)\\
&= \left [ e^{-x^2+\alpha x} \right ]_{-\infty}^{+\infty} +\frac \alpha 2 f(\alpha)\\
&=\frac \alpha 2 f(\alpha)
\end{split}$$
Solving this O.D.E. yields to $$f(\alpha)=Ce^{\frac {\alpha^2}4}$$
Since $f(0)=\sqrt{\pi}$, we have $f(\alpha)=\sqrt{\pi}e^{\frac{\alpha^2}4}$
and your integral is $\sqrt{\pi}e^{-\frac 1 4}$